# Updated EC2 instance and an EBS volume is Offline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, offline, hard-drive, amazon-ebs

I updated an EC2 Windows 2019 server instance from t3.medium to t2.medium.
The machine had a D drive for storage which is an EBS volume.  Now that volume says it's offline:

[image]

Has anyone else encountered this?  Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Well it was pretty obvious in retrospect.  Just had to right-click on the "Offline" and choose "Online".

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just had this happen to me, after changing an EC2 instance type. Nothing in the event log that indicates why, though. Setting the disk online is an easy fix, but it shouldn't be necessary.